# SharePoint rights for creating “communication sites”

Tags: communication-site

On the SharePoint pannel admin, we can decide if we autorize users to create sites or not.

The problem with it, its because Its very "all or nothing" we cant freely decide wich group had the right to create a site or a subsite...

We can disable here the thing i'm talking about, but as I said, its "all or nothing"

[image]

There is a way to control this ?